# Slow Update after Truncate

Tags: sql, oracle, truncate

I've got a relatively simple update statement:

```
update sv_konginfo ki
set AnzDarl = 1 
where kong_nr in ( 
    select kong_nr
    from sv_darlehen
    group by kong_nr
    having count (*) = 1);
```

which runs okay on its own (about 1 second for about 150.000 records).

However, if I truncate the table and then re-insert the records:

```
truncate table sv_konginfo;

insert into sv_konginfo (kong_nr)
select distinct kong_nr
from sv_darlehen;
```

the update statement runs very slow (more than a minute) working on exactly the same data.

What can I do to improve the performance in the second scenario? (We're using an Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit.)

Comment: Before you can say you've improved the performance of the update, you need to determine what is causing it to be slow in the first place. I'd start with getting execution plans before and after the truncate+insert, and I'd also want to know how many rows are being updated before and after the truncate+insert. For instance, after the insert, are there more rows in sv_konginfo than there were prior to the truncate?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but the points you mention is why I'm so perplexed by the performance: Both the data in the table and the execution plans are exactly the same!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the input, they helped me figure out what caused the problem: Chained Rows!

- after the insert of the new rows AnzDarl (and a number of other columns) are null
- when the columns are set to 1 (or other values), they occupy some more space

I was able to check this using the following SQL:

```
select chain_cnt 
from user_tables 
where table_name='SV_KONGINFO';
```

After the Truncate, the chain_cnt was 0. After running the Update, the chain_cnt increased dramatically and was equal to the number of affected rows.

Increasing PCT_FREE like this solved the performance issue for me:

```
alter table sv_konginfo pctfree 40;
```

Thanks again for the input, they helped to rule out some potential issues until finally chained rows rose to the top of my mind.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks (and +1) for sharing the solution.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting, but I guess the problem description did not do much to help pointing readers of the question in the right direction ...

Answer (score 3):

My first guess would be an

```
ANALYZE TABLE sv_konginfo COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

or using `DBMS_STATS`. Have a look at [Managing Schema Objects](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/general.htm#sthref1861).

Comment: That was my first guess, too, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, the problem is totally reproducible. See my own answer for what was going on.