# What is row locking and chaining in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

What is row locking and chaining in Oracle and what is its impact on performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Row locking](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm#sthref2066) and [Row chaining](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/logical.htm#sthref338) are two entirely different concepts.

- **Row Locking** is a mechanism that enables multiple users to modify the same table in a reliable, consistent fashion. It has no impact on performance since you can't disable it.
- **Row Chaining** is when a row is too large to fit in a single data block and is split over two or more blocks. Having **very** large rows may impact performance. Basically Oracle will have to visit more blocks to reconstruct each chained row. In particular, this will add IOs on ACCESS BY ROWID operations.

Comment: +1. Very large rows are not the only reason for Row Chaining though, updating existing rows with larger values can also lead to that -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020231/slow-update-after-truncate/2021259#2021259

Comment: @Peter: that would be Row Migrating :)